# Python 3.4 - returning rankings based on two sets of data (with one only used when the other produces a tie)

Tags: python, sorting, ranking

I am working on a league table program in Python 3.4.3, where there are four teams and I need to produce a ranking for them based on total points and away points, where the team with the most total points wins, and the away points are used to resolve equal total points counts (more away points is better). I have variables for all these values, I just need to somehow recieve rankings for them.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
# loading points from file
pointsfile = open("points.txt", "r+")
pointsfile.seek(0, 0)
apoints = str(int(pointsfile.read(2)))
pointsfile.seek(2, 0)
bpoints = str(int(pointsfile.read(2)))
pointsfile.seek(4, 0)
cpoints = str(int(pointsfile.read(2)))
pointsfile.seek(6, 0)
dpoints = str(int(pointsfile.read(2)))
pointsfile.close()

# loading away points from file
awayfilea = open("awaypointsa.txt", "r+")
awayfileb = open("awaypointsb.txt", "r+")
awayfilec = open("awaypointsc.txt", "r+")
awayfiled = open("awaypointsd.txt", "r+")
aaway = awayfilea.read()
baway = awayfileb.read()
caway = awayfilec.read()
daway = awayfiled.read()
awayfilea.close()
awayfileb.close()
awayfilec.close()
awayfiled.close()

# attempting to sort using a dictionary (works assuming no teams have equal points)
pointsdict = {"a": apoints, "b": bpoints, "c": cpoints, "d": dpoints}
pointsdictsorted = sorted(pointsdict, key=pointsdict.__getitem__, reverse=True)
print(pointsdictsorted)
```

I would like the results in the format:

```
arank = [value]
brank = [value]
crank = [value]
drank = [value]
```

where [value] is a number from 1 to 4, with 1 being for the highest number of points.
I am not a huge expert in programming, so please keep explanations fairly simple.

Many thanks in advance for your help,
barnstorm3r

(Yes, I know that a list would be more efficient for storing values such as these, but the rest of the code (nearly 600 lines) is set up for individual variables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pointsdict = {"a": apoints, "b": bpoints, "c": cpoints, "d": dpoints}
pointsdictsorted = sorted(pointsdict, key=pointsdict.__getitem__, reverse=True)
print(pointsdictsorted)

# Take the sorted list of values, and create a tuple for each: (value, rank)
for idx, elem in enumerate(pointsdictsorted):
    pointsdictsorted[idx] = (elem, idx + 1)

# Resort for teams, not scores, and assign.
ranks = sorted(pointsdictsorted)
arank = ranks[0][1]
brank = ranks[1][1]
crank = ranks[2][1]
drank = ranks[3][1]

print(arank, brank, crank, drank)
```